# What is an English equivalent of 'Colorín, Colorado, este cuento se ha acabado,' a phrase used at the end of stories?

Tags: phrase-requests, translation, spanish, story

*Colorín, Colorado, este cuento se ha acabado* is a Spanish phrase used to indicate that a story has reached its end. The first part is just nonsense, the second part means 'this story is over.'

We use a similar phrase in Tamil, கதை முடிந்தது கத்திரிக்காய் காச்சத்து. It means, literally, 'the story is over, the eggplant is ripe'.

Is there an equivalent, semi-nonsensical phrase in English used by storytellers to tell their listeners that the story is over?

I can't think of anything besides the not-always-applicable *...and they all lived happily ever after*, which isn't nonsensical, and I couldn't find any useful translations of the Spanish phrase anywhere online either.

Comment: This sounds sort of like *tomayto* / *tomahto (for *tomato*): [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/tomayto,_tomahto): (idiomatic) Used to dismissively suggest that something is a distinction without a difference. In the Spanish it seems like *Red or red, this story is read.*

Comment: This seems more a fit for Writing SE, if you're discussing how to end stories. Questions about particular idioms would belong on ELU SE.

Comment: I believe that Writing.SE is far more appropriate for this question. It's very much opinion-based.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I disagree. This question is a phrase request, which is not a good fit for Writing.

Comment: @Laurel Phrase requests are based on semantics. This is about 'an equivalent, semi-nonsensical phrase in English used by storytellers to tell their listeners that the story is over': a literary formula. And as the answers show, 'there isn't any widely used phrase' ... which makes the suggestions outside common usage and POB.

Comment: In Spanish, OP's phrase is meant to be _spoken_ (at least where I live in Chile). It isn't literary. I bet you a nickel the Tamil phrase also rhymes (I can only see little boxes in stead of Tamil writing, which I don't know how to read anyhow) and is often used at the end of a bedtime story. I'm with @Laurel: this question belongs here.

Comment: The Hungarian version is *itt a vége, fuss el véle* "here is the end, [you should] run away with it". Like everyone else, I don't know of an English version, at least not one that rhymes.

Comment: It's not "semi-nonsensical", but among the most common ways for a storyteller to explicitly indicate the end of a story in English is "the end".  That can be used whether the story is spoken or printed.

Comment: @Conrado It says (in crude phonetic spelling which nevertheless takes no account of the various alterations the written Tamil language tends to undergo in the numerous spoken dialects) kadhai mudindhadhu katthirikkaay kaacchatthu. It has a pleasing sort of sound to it and a kind of assonance/consonance, but rhyme isn't necessarily a prominent feature of the poetics of many world cultures. See also, if you're interested https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhyme#Tamil It's not really rhyme in the way that dreary rhymes with weary in English poetics

Comment: Probably doesn't count, but there is also "[So long, and thanks for all the fish!](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/So_Long,_and_Thanks_for_All_the_Fish)"

Comment: "And that's all I have to say about that" --Forrest Gump

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There is a rhyming phrase that can be considered an equivalent phrase in English, used in story endings:

> Snip, snap, snout, This tale's told out.

One of the sources where it is mentioned is a blog post of a fairy tales enthusiast and some other lesser known or one-off phrases are mentioned also: [writinginmargins.weebly.com](https://writinginmargins.weebly.com/home/fairy-tale-endings)

> Everyone knows the standard opening and closing formulas, from "Once upon a time " to "happily ever after." But "happily ever after" is not the only way to conclude a tale.

> I'm fond of "Snip, snap, snout, This tale's told out," or the Spanish equivalent:  "Colorín, colorado, Este cuento se ha acabado." (This story is over.) Some folktales from the Hausa people of Africa conclude with the phrase "Off with the rat's head."

Note: I don't know how common this phrase is but it is mentioned in many sources. It was used in a Norwegian fairy tale called "Three Billy Goats Gruff", possibly in the English translation published as "Popular Tales from the Norse" first per some sources. I believe other fairy tales may have used it also. The OP's intention is finding a rhyming phrase with a meaningless first part used at the end of stories, and a fairy tale enthusiast mentions this phrase as an equivalent of the Spanish phrase.

Comment: Is that an American English thing?  It's not any part of British English story endings that I'm aware of, and I'm not sure that page considers it to be common usage.

Comment: @Graham Not an American thing. Never heard of it.

Comment: I don't recognize that one at all.  That doesn't mean I've never heard it, but I don't accept that it has been more than regionally common (in what region I don't know) over the last fifty or so years.

Comment: Does is matter which English as long as it works?

Comment: My grandma had a set of books with fairy tales and some of them ended with that phrase.  I remember "The Runaway Pancake" being one of them.  The books were old sixty years ago.

Comment: This is very close to the Swedish version "Snipp, snapp, snut. Så var sagan slut.", which is used exactly like the Spanish one, so I guess this could be of Scandinavian origin.

Comment: @B.Goddard I think the "The Runaway Pancake" may also be one of the [Norwegian Folktales](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norwegian_Folktales) collected and published by Peter Christen Asbjørnsen and Jørgen Moe, just like "Three Billy Goats Gruff" mentioned by ermanen. It's listed as number 104 in the Wikipedia article with the English title "The Pancake". It may have been Asbjørnsen and Moe who popularized this as an ending to fairy tales, although variants of this rhyme seems to predate them.

Comment: @Lambie I think what other commenters are getting at is that this phrase might not be common in _any_ of the major dialects of English. I mean, there has to be some explanation for the fact that a topical expert (?) suggests it as an equivalent of the Spanish phrase and yet many English-speaking readers have never even heard of it.

Comment: It's likely the OA comes from a family of Scandinavian descent or an areas with a strong history thereof - I know this from the Norwegian version but never knew it as something said in English.

Comment: @jkej And also the Danish version, _Snip, snap, snude, så er den historie ude_. In Danish, it often continues with _tip, tap, tønde, så kan en ny begynde_ (‘tip, tap, tin, a new one can begin’). Never knew it was a pan-Scandinavian thing, much less that it had even been transferred over to English.

Comment: @B.Goodard In the original publications by Asbjørnsen and Moe ([available on](https://no.wikisource.org/wiki/Folkeeventyr_(1852)) [Wikisource](https://no.wikisource.org/wiki/Norske_Folke-_og_Huldre-Eventyr)), "Three Billy Goats Gruff" seems to be the only fairy tale ending like this (I didn't check all of them, but more than half). The exact version used there is "Snip, Snap, Snude, saa er det Eventyr ude.". The "The Pancake" ends with "»Nøf, kof« sagde Grisen og tog Pandekagen i een Jafs, og da Pandekagen ikke kom længer, er ikke Ræglen længer heller."

Comment: cont. My translation: "»Oink, oink« said the Pig and took the Pancake in one go, and since the Pancake didn't get any further, neither does this story." The only other fairy tale that I found with an ending somewhat similar to "Snap, snap, snout..." was "Kulbrænderen" which ends like this "Trip trap trille, han blev mere end han vilde.". This one doesn't seem to have caught on though. So if "Snip, Snap, snout..." was popularized by Asbjørnsen and Moe, it was probably mainly through "Three Billy Goats Gruff", although this ending may have been added to later versions of their fairy tales.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Searching the web, I found that a version with "snute/ute" is also sometimes used in Swedish similarly to in Danish and in the Norwegian original. I have never heard it before though, and to me it sounds a little clunky. I imagine that might be one of the reasons that the English version never really caught on. It doesn't roll as nicely off the tongue as in the Scandinavian languages.

Comment: @Lambie I don't believe it was *ever* in common usage. I'll assert as an English person that it was never a common part of English or Scottish stories, at least as written down. It doesn't sound American, or Australian, or Irish. That kind of limits the options. And "as long as it works" requires the reader to be familiar with it. I'd confidently assert that even if this was ever recorded as part of a story (which itself is questionable), your chances of finding someone familiar with it are so close to zero as makes no difference.

Comment: @Graham I know all that but I say if it works, why not? Literary translation allows for that sort of thing. Not everything I read that is new is something I am familiar with. :) It all depends on where the expression occurs.

Comment: @Lambie Sure, you can always invent an original phrase (which it appears this one is). But the OP wanted something which is colloquial English, and that kind of rules out new inventions.

Answer (score 20):

The Spanish phrase is a rhyme which evokes childhood memories because many folk stories used to end in that way. Nowadays, in normal speech, it is used in a humorous way to say that something is finished.

In English, there is a phrase that is not a rhyme, but evokes childhood memories and is a humorous way to say "the end". However, it has to do more with cartoons than with books:

> ***That's all folks!***
> *humorous* Used to indicate or emphasize that something has finished or concluded. Popularized as the catchphrase featured at the end of episodes in the animated series Looney Tunes, often said aloud by the character Porky Pig.
>
> - And there's the last bell of the school year! That's all, folks! Enjoy your summer vacation! ([FreeDict](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/That%27s+all%2C+folks!))

Comment: Or "Th-th-th-that's all, folks!"

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if this has been supplanted by "thanks for coming to my TED talk" these days. I'm curious about how many people 25 and under would even get "That's all folks!" beyond intuition and not the reference itself

Comment: @roganjosh It’s not like children aren’t still watching the old classic cartoons. Even here in Scandinavia, they still regularly show Looney Tunes on telly, and kids still happily watch it. I think a lot more young people would be familiar with “That’s all folks!” than with “Thanks for coming to my TED talk”, _especially_ children.

Answer (score 14):

There isn't any widely used phrase. As for something lesser known, the ending of [The Iron Stove](https://fairytalez.com/the-iron-stove/) by the Brothers Grimm fits the format, even matching the rhyme from the Spanish:

> A mouse did run,
> The story is done.

Just like both the Tamil and Spanish phrases, this is a non-sequitur: There is no mouse in the story.

Answer (score 10):

### No, there isn't.

As you correctly state, the traditional ending that fulfils the same role in English is "... and they all lived happily ever after". While there are other endings that follow a similar form in English they are all only occasionally used.

Answer (score 3):

One common trope is to briefly mention further events in the protagonists' lives, and then to say

> But that's another story.

In the tradition of oral storytelling, this sets up expectations for future stories.  But it also tells the listener that the current story is over.

I would not say that this is exactly equivalent to a conventional nonsense phrase at the end of a story though.

Answer (score 2):

This is *not* English, but many people in Ireland who are essentially monolingual English speakers will still have some words and phrases of Irish, and will use them occasionally. Folk tales in Irish traditionally end with *sin é* (that's it), and this phrase is definitely found in Hiberno-English.

Answer (score 1):

> The End

Many books have this ending, short and sweet.

Answer (score 0):

A Dream/Not the End

It's not a "classic" like happily ever after but for a while I read stories with "and it was all a dream" or "and then I woke up". Giving people the sense that everything the character went through was simply a dream.

Also, read  alot of "this is not the end" or "this/their/the story has just begun". This is straight forward and probably what gave way to many a series. But I've also seen it used for standalone books too.

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned

**They lived happily ever after.**

You can play around with this fixed phrase, for example

*"they lived happily ever after (for a while.)"*

See also this ironic example from Nadine Gorimer:

*"in the house where they were living happily ever after they now saw the trees and sky through bars."*

.

Equally common is just

**The end**

Answer (score -2):

My reply will be simply anecdotal, for lack of any phrase that legitimately satisfies your question. I don't believe there is one. From my 50 years reading to children, being a literacy tutor, and listening to storytellers whenever possible, I don't recall ever hearing a nonsensical rhyme to end a tale.

For my children at bedtime, we always finished story time with this:

Now I lay me down to sleep
I pray the Lord my soul to keep
May angels watch me through the night
And keep me in their bless-ed sight
Amen
(Hug and a kiss on the forehead with a tuck-in and, "Sweet dreams, my sweetheart. I love you, infinity times forever".)

They're all grown up now. Thank you for bringing that back to mind.